# How can I get dynamically generated html in txt file in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an empty div in my aspx page and I am generating dynamic content in that div.

```
<div id="book"> </div>
```

After loading content of my div

```
<div id="book">
    <div class=’a’ style=”left: 0px ; width:469px;"> … </div>
    <div class=’b’ style=”left: 0px ; width:469px;"> … </div>
    <div class=’c’ style=”left: 0px ; width:469px;"> … </div>
</div>
```

I want  html code in one txt file. So basically my txt file contain data :

```
<div class=’a’ style=”left: 0px ; width:469px;"> … </div>
<div class=’b’ style=”left: 0px ; width:469px;"> … </div>
<div class=’c’ style=”left: 0px ; width:469px;"> … </div>
```

Is there any functionality for such things in jQuery ? Please help me.

Comment: so you want to load the content of the txt file to the div `#book`

Comment: where is the txt file saved and what is the url to the txt file

Comment: @ArunPJohny Stackoverflow is not really there for providing finished solutions...

Comment: I want to load html code of <div id="book"> in to txt file.

Comment: I don't think it can be done in the client side alone, you may have to sent the contents of the div to server and then sent back the txt file from server with the desired contents

Comment: Another possible solution will be is to use [html5 file API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)

Comment: Also you should refrain from using `’` and instead use either `'` or `"` consistently across your code.

Comment: @ArunPJohny of course it can be done client-side only... that is the whole point of AJAX after all.. you just need to provide an element, where the response is supposed to be inserted into with ('#el').html(response)

Comment: @Vogel612 no, I think the requirement is different, he need to copy the contents of the html element to a file

Comment: @ArunPJohny dafuq... that makes literally no sense. he generates the code (which will presumably happen server-side) and then sends it back to the server to save it in a text-file....

Answer (score 0):

check [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/JQuery.ajax)

it was specially designed to dynamically load content into given Elements

This link refers to JQuery, you can do it in plain javascript, but then the code expands to the triple of lines you'd need with JQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'path/to/file.txt',
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function(html) {
        $('#book').html(html);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// get contents of div, set to variable txt
var txt = $('#book').html();

// send contents of txt to asp handler,
// ie. some function that takes an input and saves it on your server
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType : 'html',
    url: "handler.asp",
    data: txt         
});

request.done(function(data){
    // success
    console.log(data);
});

request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus,responseText){
    // failed
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus,responseText)
});
```

Comment: why would you need to send some data to a getter... i mean you don't really need processing here. also... why would you send flat html and not some form-data